# Getting "JDBC driver does not support JDBC 4.1 'getObject(int, Class)' method java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException"

Tags: sql-server, database, exception, logging, jdbc

I am getting this log when using JDBC driver version 6.1.0.jre8 for SQL server after I started using Hikari instead of tomcat-jdbc version 9.0.22.

```
    JDBC driver does not support JDBC 4.1 'getObject(int, Class)' method
java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: This operation is not supported.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.getObject(SQLServerResultSet.java:2384) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.1.0.jre8.jar!/:?]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyResultSet.getObject(HikariProxyResultSet.java) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:?]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.getResultSetValue(JdbcUtils.java:212) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.BeanPropertyRowMapper.getColumnValue(BeanPropertyRowMapper.java:378) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.BeanPropertyRowMapper.mapRow(BeanPropertyRowMapper.java:299) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:94) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.processResultSet(JdbcTemplate.java:1289) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.extractReturnedResults(JdbcTemplate.java:1185) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.lambda$call$4(JdbcTemplate.java:1155) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:1091) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.call(JdbcTemplate.java:1146) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcCall.executeCallInternal(AbstractJdbcCall.java:412) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcCall.doExecute(AbstractJdbcCall.java:395) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcCall.execute(SimpleJdbcCall.java:192) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at com.expedia.lodging.bookstore.db.DBHandlerAbstract.exec(DBHandlerAbstract.java:303) ~[classes!/:cef38306d33bbfc5561283b534fe2ea119944c84-1848]
    at com.expedia.lodging.bookstore.db.DBHandlerAbstract.callSprocWithMultipleResultSets(DBHandlerAbstract.java:214) ~[classes!/:cef38306d33bbfc5561283b534fe2ea119944c8
```

When added checked against the method which was logging this , it was found that it is not impac ting the workflow just adding additional logging.

I had this investigation done around this wherein SQL Server does not implement `getObject(int, Class)` method which is JDBC driver 4.1 specification.

JDBC 4.1 is the JDBC standard which imposes each driver vendor to implement certain methods. Same is the case for `getObject(int, Class)` methods which should be implemented as a part of JDBC standards for API version 4.1 .
https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDBC/jdbcvers.htm#JJDBC29008

The above is a warning that the driver being used does not support `getObject(int, Class)` method and is not causing any problem for us because we are not using this method anywhere in capture.

I searched MS SQL Server documentation, but could not find the implementation.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/reference/getobject-method-int-java-util-map?view=sql-server-ver15

Is there a way to disable this logging?

Comment: Have you tried updating to a newer version. The 6.1.0.jre8 version is relatively old. The most recent (for Java 8) is 8.2.2.jre8, and looking at [its sources](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-jdbc/blob/dev/src/main/java/com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerResultSet.java#L2365) it is implemented in recent versions.

Comment: And FYI, this is not just some warning that is logged by the driver: it is an exception thrown by the driver, which might have been caught somewhere in your application or a library you're using, possibly applying a fallback to `getObject(int)`, or - worse - ignoring the problem.